# Problema con los rangos al generar un histograma

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Me gustaría crear un histograma de frecuencias, definiendo los rangos de cada barrita en el histograma. Creí que al definir el número de barras, se definirían sus rangos pero no he logrado obtener un histograma deseado.

el código que estoy tratando de usar es el siguiente:

```
 qplot(b2$residual2,
+       geom="histogram",
+       binwidth = 20,  
+       xlab = "Gruop of Residual",  
+       ylab = "Number of ocurrencies",  
+       fill=I("blue"), 
+       col=I("black"), 
+       alpha=I(.2),
+       xlim=c(-300,300))
```

Podrían sugerirme cómo hacerlo? al intentar hacerlo con ggplot2, me genera error:

```
ggplot(b2, aes(residual2))+ + geom_histogram(bin=30) Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: bin stat_bin() using bins = 30. Pick better value with binwidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Veamos, el error (que en realidad es un warning)

> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: bin stat_bin() using bins = 30.
>   Pick better value with binwidth

se debe básicamente por que `geom_histogram()` no tiene un parámetro `bin` sino que se llama `bins`, si ejecutas `?geom_histogram()` podrás ver la ayuda

```
bins     Number of bins. Overridden by binwidth. Defaults to 30
```

No estás mal encaminado para graficar un histograma. Puedes usar

```
# Genero un data.frame de ejemplo
set set.seed(300)
b2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(residual2=sample(1:30, 1000,replace = TRUE)))

ggplot(data=b2, aes(b2$residual2)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins=30)
```

Con lo que conseguirías algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O bien

```
qplot(b2$residual2,
      geom="histogram",
      binwidth = 0.5,  
      xlab = "Gruop of Residual",  
      ylab = "Number of ocurrencies",  
      fill=I("blue"), 
      col=I("black"), 
      alpha=I(.2),
      xlim=c(1,30))
```

Dónde deberías:

- Modificar `binwidth = 20`, que es el ancho de cada barra no la cantidad por algo así `binwidth = 0.5` un ancho más pequeño para poder ver todas
- Y `xlim=c(-300,300)` por `xlim=c(1,30)` para asemejarlo al ejemplo anterior en el que establecías 30 barras, acá lo que estamos diciendo es limitar la barras a mostrar a las primeras 30, eso variará según lo que necesites

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]